# Why is the sequence of sopfr($n!$) so similar to the sequence of the number of diagonals in $n$-polygons?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polygons, pattern-recognition

Could someone please enlighten me on why the sequence of `sopfr(n!)` (the sum of prime factors of `n!`) is seemingly related to the number of diagonals in $n$-polygons?  What is the relation between them? How do these puzzle pieces connect, intuitively?

As a refresher, the `sopfr(n)` function (or the integer log of `n`) calculates the sum of all distinct prime factors of a positive integer `n`, each raised to the power of its multiplicity. For eg., `12` in terms of its prime factors is `2^2 * 3^1`. `sopfr(n)`, then, would be `2^2 + 3^1`. In other words, `sopfr(n) = Σ(p^k)` for each prime factor `p^k` of `n`, where `p` is a prime number and `k` is its multiplicity in the prime factorization of `n`.

Also, just for clarity, $n$-polygons refer to regular polygons with `n` sides starting from `3`. The number of diagonals in an $n$-polygon is the count of all the possible line segments that can be drawn between non-adjacent vertices (that is excluding the sides) of the polygon. In a triangle, the count is `0`, in a quadrilateral, it is `2`, in a pentagon, it is `5`, and so on.

The first 24 terms of the `sopfr(n!)` [sequence](https://oeis.org/A025281) are:-

```
0, 0, 2, 5, 9, 14, 19, 26, 32, 38, 45, 56, 63, 76, 85, 93, 101, 118, 126, 145, 154, 164, 177, 200, ...
```

While the first 24 terms of the [sequence](https://oeis.org/A000096) of the number of diagonals of $n$-polygons are:-

```
0, 2, 5, 9, 14, 20, 27, 35, 44, 54, 65, 77, 90, 104, 119, 135, 152, 170, 189, 209, 230, 252, 275, 299, ...
```

As is pretty clear, the first few terms are similar but then they begin to diverge.

Here is a graph showing their relation:-

[image: Graph]

All insights are extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The first is sequence $A025281$ in $OEIS$ and  in year $1977$ Alladi and Erdős gave the asymptotic
$$a_n\sim \frac{\pi ^2\, n^2}{12\, \log (n)}$$ Have a look at [this paper](https://msp.org/pjm/1977/71-2/pjm-v71-n2-p01-s.pdf).

The second one is
$$b_n=\frac {n(n+3)} 2$$

If you plot $a_n$ as a function of $b_n$ (I used $10^2 \leq n \leq 10^6$ by steps of $100$), a quick and dirty linear regression with no intercept gives with $R^2=0.999663$

$$a_n= k\, b_n$$

$$\begin{array}{l|lll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
\hline
 k & 6.87345 & 0.00399 & \{6.86561,6.88128\} \\
\end{array}$$

If, instead of the asymptotics, you use the exact values, with $R^2=0.999721$
$$\begin{array}{l|lll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
\hline
 k & 7.56504 & 0.00126 & \{7.56256,7.56751\} \\
\end{array}$$

If, to get rid of very large numbers, you compute instead the ratio $\frac {b_n}{a_n}$ and curve fit

$$\frac {b_n}{a_n}=\alpha\,\log(n)-\beta$$

with $R^2=0.99999975$

$$\begin{array}{l|lll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
\hline
 \alpha & 0.608193 & 0.000036 & \{0.608123,0.608263\} \\
 \beta  & 0.712634 & 0.000460 & \{0.711732,0.713537\} \\
\end{array}$$ for an average absolute error of $0.002$ and a maximum  absolute error of $0.171$.

Notice that $\frac {12} {2\pi^2}=0.607927$